# ASP.NET Core MVC : Okta integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, okta

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application which uses Okta for authentication. I'm experiencing a very strange issue. My Okta sandbox works great, but when I switch to my Okta Production I get the following error:

> IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. HttpResponseMessage: '[PII of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]', HttpResponseMessage.Content: '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

I set up the application the exact same in Okta production but it causes issues. Note when I switch to a different Okta integration I only change my Okta values in `appSettings.json`, (the issuer, clientId, clientSecret, and authority).

//appsettings.json

```
"Okta": {
  "Issuer": "https://Domain/oauth2/default",
  "ClientId": "hidden",
  "ClientSecret": "hidden",
  "CallbackPath": "/okta-auth",
  "Authority": "https://Domain/oauth2/default"
}
```

`Startup.cs` - `ConfigureServices` method:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddControllersWithViews();
     services.AddAuthorization();

     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
         options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "okta";
     })
         .AddCookie(options =>
         {
         })

         // let users sign in with okta account
         .AddOpenIdConnect("okta", options =>
         {
             options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Authority"];
             options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
             options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
             options.CallbackPath = Configuration["Okta:CallbackPath"];
             options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
         });
}
```

Note: my `Program.cs` also uses `app.UseAuthorization();`, `app.UseAuthorization();`.

I really don't understand what may be causing this.

Comment: What's the difference between the app settings json and now? Do you modify the Authority or issuer to use https instead of http?

Comment: Hi Brando, no it was always https I only changed the domain to be the correct one for the Okta environment

Comment: I suggest you could try to enable the highest logging level to see what's the exactly error when you get the error. Normally, this error means the production server couldn't get the required information from the identity server. I suggest you could also re-check the network to make sure you could access the identity server.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

So its because I had /oauth2/default attached to the authority and I don't have the paid feature for that. Removing it solved my issue.